# How to change/reset konsole profile settings with command line?

Tags: linux, kde-plasma, konsole

I've changed the command of '/bin/bash' to '/bin/bash fish', and now when i try to open my konsole it open and close suddenly. As i can't open the konsole i'm not able to edit the profile settings with GUI.

here is the setting i've changed:
[image: profile config]

I'm using Debian 11 with kde 5

Answer (score 0):

Maybe isn't the best solution but worked for me:

1. Open the konsole as a different suer:

   1. Search for konsole in the menu applications.
   2. Right click > Edit appliction > Application > Advanced options.
   3. Check the box 'Run as a different user', and enter the name of a user that you have acess.
2. Now open konsole (as the different user you have set previously.
3. Login as the main user using:

   ```
   su yourNameUser
   ```
4. Look for one of these three locations and delete the profile settings causing problems.

   ```
      - /home/nameUser/.config/konsolerc
      - /home/nameUser/.local/share/konsole
      - /home/nameUser/.local/share/kxmlgui5/konsole/
   ```
5. Uncheck the box 'Run as a different' checked in the step 2

Answer (score 0):

The config files are in /.local/share/konsole/

The file where the '/bin/bash fish' command is has a .profile extension. For example on my system it's breath2.profile. Look for this line:

```
[General]
Command=/bin/bash fish
```